# Problem with displaying Table in Android, Please help

Tags: android, onclick, tablelayout

HI,

I want to create a table in android, should contains a lot of rows. Each row has 4 columns, and if i click any view, i want to integrate onClick event for the view.
I have developed something similar to the requirement,But didn't got the click view, Here is my code :

LinearLayout lLayout1= null;
    LinearLayout main_lLayout= null;
    LinearLayout lLayout2= null;
    TextView myText[] = new TextView[12];

```
LinearLayout myLayout[] = new LinearLayout[12];
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icici) {
    super.onCreate(icici);

    main_lLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    main_lLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    main_lLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    int k = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        myLayout[i] = new LinearLayout(this);

        for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {
            myText[j] = new TextView(this);
            myText[j].setText("asdf"+i+j);
            myText[j].setPadding(0, 0, 20, 10);
            myText[j].setClickable(true);
            myText[j].setId(k);
            myText[j].setOnClickListener(this);
            k++;
            System.out.println(k);
            myLayout[i].addView(myText[j]);

        }       
        main_lLayout.addView(myLayout[i]);

    }       
    setContentView(main_lLayout);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    System.out.println(myText[0].getText());
    System.out.println(myText[10].getText());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some bad array management there... you're instantiating 16 TextViews but only assign them to the first 4 elements of myText. If you fix this I find the click handler is called as expected.